# Passing Data from TableView to ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I'm trying to send data from a table view to a viewController but it keeps crashing. Here is what i have done:

in prepare for segue

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]){
    DetailView *dv = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    dv.stringForFirstLabel = [_cell.firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
 }
```

but it logs this

> : unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Comment: On which method ?...

Comment: make sure you named the segue correctly in storyboard, and that name matches with the one you entered while performing segue.

Comment: the `_cell` looks kinda strange. what is that?

Comment: It usually also logs, which instance did not recognize the selector. Please share that as well.

Comment: Please try to specify details about your code. For example, there is no way to understand what is _cell. Secondly, try to copy paste the exact code, you are try. for example, the 1st line is if ([segue.identifier isEqualToStrinf:@"detailSegue"]){ which itself should give a compile time error because there is no method called isEqualToStrinf.

Comment: _cell is a class of a UITableViewCell

Comment: Do you have a custom cell sublass? Otherwise it won't have a property named `firstArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Might it be because you call the method `isEqualToStrinf` which should be `isEqualToString`?

Comment: There is no method or selector named isEqualToStrinf under NSString interface. @Udondan is right. [segue.identifier isEqualToStrinf:@"detailSegue"] should cause a compile time error.

Comment: If that is the case, it will give compile time error, not crash.

Comment: isEqualToStrinf is just a typo

Comment: i just want to pass a string that is inside the UITableViewCell to a detail View but if there's more than one cell in the tableView it runs perfectly but when i select a cell and go to the detail view that string that i passed is equal to the last cell from the tableView it doesnt matter if i select the second cell or the third cell the string will be equal to the last cell. Thats what i'm trying to fix.

Comment: That is relevant information. Please update the original question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to piece together some ideas based on your comments (unfortunately your question is phrased and structured very poorly):

I assume you are trying to pass the text of the label of the selected table view cell to a detail view controller.

I think a clean implementation would be the following:

You have an array property of strings that serves as a data source for the table view cells, which you set up in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myStrings = @[@"Title 1", @"Title 2", @"Title 3"];
}
```

So in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can set the text of the `titleLabel` property of the cell to the given item, e.g.:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // ...

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
    cell.titleLabel.text = self.myStrings[indexPath.row];

    // ...

    return cell;
}
```

Then in `prepareForSegue`, you could query the selected index:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"])
    {
        DetailView *dv = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *text = self.myStrings[indexPath.row];

        dv.stringForFirstLabel = text;
    }
}
```